# How to check which Disk and Partition I am using to boot this system?

Tags: boot

I want to know which disk and partition I am using to boot this system?

For example (hd0,0)

I got this:

```
luke@ubuntu:~$ sudo fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 30.1 GB, 30064771072 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 3655 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00012b4f

   Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1        3499    28101632   83  Linux
/dev/sda2            3499        3656     1255425    5  Extended
/dev/sda5            3499        3656     1255424   82  Linux swap / Solaris
luke@ubuntu:~$
```

But it doesn't tell me about (hd?,?)

Answer (score 2):

The designation `(hd0,0)` is from GRUB, the boot loader. In your example, above, `hd0` refers to `/dev/sda`, and the `,0` refers to the first partition - making the boot device `/dev/sda1`.

There is a complete [manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub.html) on GRUB from the GNU project.

Comment: The link provided is to a specific instance of grub documentation. FWIW, I thought it might also help to provide the link a level or so up to the [Grub Documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/grub/grub-documentation.html) page. Looks as though there are links to Grub tutorials on that page.

Answer (score 2):

Try to type mount it would display a bunch of data, what you need to know is where the /boot goes

```
$ mount
/dev/mapper/colliseum-root on / type ext4 (rw,errors=remount-ro)
proc on /proc type proc (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
none on /sys type sysfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
fusectl on /sys/fs/fuse/connections type fusectl (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/debug type debugfs (rw)
none on /sys/kernel/security type securityfs (rw)
none on /dev type devtmpfs (rw,mode=0755)
none on /dev/pts type devpts (rw,noexec,nosuid,gid=5,mode=0620)
none on /dev/shm type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,nodev)
none on /var/run type tmpfs (rw,nosuid,mode=0755)
none on /var/lock type tmpfs (rw,noexec,nosuid,nodev)
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext2 (rw)
$
```

That was my output so you need to know that

```
/dev/sda1 on /boot type ext2 (rw)
```

**conclusion**: my boot partition is sda1, in grub would be (hd0,0)